# What is the correct way to loop through this array of objects inside of render, react

Tags: reactjs

What is the correct way to loop through each 'repo'?

```
 ...
render(){
    const watchers = [];
    const names = [];

    this.props.repos.map(repo => (
        names.push(repo.name)
        watchers.push(repo.watchers) 
    ));
    return(...)
}
```

Comment: What is the wrong with this? Just add undefined check `this.props.repos && this.props.repos.map `

Comment: Instead `map` use `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be

```
...
render(){
    const watchers = this.props.repos.map(r => r.watchers);
    const names = this.props.repos.map(r => name);
    return(...)
}
```

Comment: Why there is a need to loop two time.?What is the wrong with above?